# How to Setup the interpreter for visual studio code to use

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I tried to follow the steps in this video "Python - Setup Visual Studio Code with Anaconda"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sts3CFewvkY

Press Ctrl+Shift+P, and open "Preferences:Open User Settings".
Then Search for "Python Path"

In the video, I can see the "Python:Python Path" below "Python:Poetry Path" with following information
"Python:Python Path
Path to Python, you can use a custom version of Python by modifying this serring to include the full path"

However, I didn't find Python Path.  I can only see "Python>Testing:Pytese path" below "Python:Poetry Path".

Would you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup Visual Studio Code with Anaconda
Follow the following video (But following the instruction in the following step 4 not in the video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sts3CFewvkY

1. google search "download anaconda"
2. Install anaconda with all the recommended settings
3. Open visual studio code, install "Python extension for Visual Studio Code"
4. Press Ctrl+Shift+P, and open "Preferences:Open User Settings".
   Then Search for “Python:Default Interpreter Path”. The input location is where I installed anaconda.

The version of my Visual studio code is 1.85.1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).